# Is there a variety such that a regular model is known but not a semistable model?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a smooth projective variety over a complete discretely valued field such that a regular model is known but no semistable model is known?

Models after a finite possibly ramified extension also count.

Comment: Welcome ansog. Let $X$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with additive reduction. Such an elliptic curve has a minimal regular model (consider, for example $y^2 = x^3+p$ with $p>3$) but not a semistable model over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.